# Unable to download file from swagger

Tags: java, io, swagger-2.0

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Perfect") })
public void getLabel(@QueryParam("orderItemsId") String orderItemsId,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse response) {
    String dataDirectory = httpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/files/label.pdf");
    Path file = Paths.get(dataDirectory);
    if (Files.exists(file))
    {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"label.pdf\"");
        try
        {
            Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using springfox-swagger2 - version 2.5.0 with springfox-swagger-ui - version 2.5.0.

without content-Disposition header swagger is unable to sync output file in swagger-ui, it shows data in binary form(i guess)kind-of corrupted and whereas with this header i get a link in ResponseBody which also downloads pdf but corrupted form same as it syncs in swagger-ui.

I have done a research it shows we need to provide datatype:"file" in response [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/486) . but @ApiResponse doesn't contain any datatype field. Though it has field with response but i am not sure what class to give for 
octet-stream output. I have tried OutputStream but it doesn't work.

Edit : Swagger UI does not support the downloading of file. whereas same url if called through other source will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI does not support the downloading of file. whereas same url if called through other source will do the job.